# SAS PROC SQL difference in what SAS does

Tags: sas, proc-sql

What is the difference in terms of what I'm asking the SAS engine to execute between these three code samples?

**SAMPLE A**

```
PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE foo AS 
SELECT
    aaa
FROM
   table1
;

CREATE TABLE bar AS 
SELECT
    aaa
FROM
   foo
;
```

**SAMPLE B**

```
PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE foo AS 
SELECT
    aaa
FROM
   table1
;

PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE bar AS                        /* Difference is here */
SELECT
    aaa
FROM
   foo
;
```

**SAMPLE C**

```
PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE foo AS 
SELECT
    aaa
FROM
   table1
;

QUIT;                                                /* Difference is here */

PROC SQL; CREATE TABLE bar AS 
SELECT
    aaa
FROM
   foo
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Proc SQL` treats each section that ends with a semi-colon (`;`)as a statement, and will continue to do so until you submit `quit ;`. Apart from the lack of a `quit` statement at the end, the first block is fine, as is the third. The second block has an extraneous `Proc SQL`, that just stops and starts the SQL submission, which isn't very good code. The first and third blocks are equally good for programming, the first will run slightly quicker than the third, but if the first part of the sql fails then the whole proc will fail, whereas the third block of code is slightly slower, but if the first `proc sql` fails, the second will still be run.

Comment: There will be a slight difference in the results window (I know that tables are created here, so it's irrelevant). 1 will output both results to a single window, 2 and 3 will output to separate windows

Comment: `if the first part of the sql fails then the whole proc will fail` is not true.  `proc sql;
create table foo as select * from bar;
create table want as select * from sashelp.class;
quit;
`  does create a `want` dataset, for example.  It reports the PROC ended with errors, which is correct, but it does not stop executing the proc (unless you're in batch mode, but then it would end either way).

Answer (score 1):

Any `PROC` statement that ends with a `QUIT` allows you to run multiple 'commands' from inside it.  Say you're doing data exploration in SQL, you could enter your `PROC SQL` statement, and submit and execute your SQL commands 1 by 1 without having to issue a `PROC SQL` each time.  When you're done you finally issue `QUIT`.

This was designed more for those people that work in SAS from a command line interface than for those that work in a GUI.

Another example would be the `PROC DATASETS` statement.

SAS will automatically recognize the end of a `PROC SQL` statement and automatically submit the `QUIT;` or `RUN;` code for you if it encounters certain other statement boundaries, like the beginning of another PROC.  However, it's good programming practice to always explicitly end your `PROC` statements with the appropriate `RUN;` or `QUIT;` statement as it improves readability of your code.

Personally with `PROC SQL` I prefer to add the noprint option (`PROC SQL noprint;`) so that it doesn't generate output to the results window.  If I want to see the results, I'll view the table using the explorer as I find that better suited to the task and it keeps my results window cleaner.  I also like to issue no more than 1 statement within each `PROC SQL` so that I can run them individually and see their performance.

Comment: I thought ending a `PROC SQL` with a `RUN;` was 'bad'? Source unverified.

Comment: Correct - The proper syntax to end a PROC SQL statement is with a QUIT. I've clarified the confusing sentence.   THanks.